# Как установить fiddler на Linux Mint в России бесплатно?

Tags: fiddler

не могу установить так как пишет что триальная версия не доступна в моём регионе. Может есть какие то сборки готовые уже. или что то ещё. каждый раз включать VPN нет желания при его использовании. Или может есть какие то аналоги данной программы для изучения https трафика.